# Any way for pandoc to print numbered sections in plain text output?

Tags: sectioning, pandoc

Here is my LaTeX input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\section{bar}
\end{document}
```

I run the following command using pandoc 1.11.1:

```
pandoc -o test.txt -t plain -N test.tex
```

And here is what I get:

```
foo
===

bar
===
```

Is there a way to have the plain text sections and subsections numbered automatically?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems that the `--number-section` option is writer-dependent, and works only with LaTeX, ConTeXt, HTML, or EPUB output.  So I think the answer is No.  If you use ATX headers, you could fairly simply post-process the headers to number them, I should think.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Pandoc output, not the TeX side of using Pandoc.
